# make ajax request from sub directory

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, request

My question is, how can i make an ajax request from a page in sub directory and get its responce.
 Here, My page `index.jsp` is placed inside a sub directory `/vf2`, inside it i have included the script file

```
<script src="../script/testscript.js"></script>
```

### testscript.js

```
function getPlaceFromIP3(){

        var ipAdd="1";
         var params ="ipAdd="+ipAdd;     
         var resultStringX = $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url:"result_page.jsp",
             data: params,
             async: false
                }).responseText;
         alert(resultStringX);

        }
```

The page `result_page.jsp` is included in the `public_html` directory itself.
When i invoke the function from `index.jsp` I am getting a page not found message. How could i send request to a page in the main directory from the sub directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And if it were a normal link how would you link to it? The same thing apply here. Use a proper relative url to the file. Start the URL from the root.

if the file is located at `http://www.example.com/result_page.jsp`, it would be

```
url:"/result_page.jsp",
```

Comment: Sir, i have tried your code but no luck. I still get a message like "The requested resource (/result_page.jsp) is not available"

Comment: How would you link to it via a URL if you typed it into the address bar?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/MyProject/vf-2/index.jsp(page from i request)
http://localhost:8080/MyProject/result_page.jsp(the requested page)

Comment: well it would be `url:"/MyProject/result_page.jsp",`